# Grid layout for a Web application

Tags: grid

I am wondering what the appropriate grid layout for a web application is. I am using a 16-grid layout which leaves at least 130px of left and right margin. However, I see application which seem to not have that space, and seem to use the entire width of the screen. Is there any thoughts that you can help me with?

Answer (score -1):

Try this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

12 cols and works with many rows. This is the go-to for rows & cols.